# AnyIP feature together with ndppd works on some VPS and doesn't on some others. Why?

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have VPSs mostly from the same provider but located in different places. They come with a single IPv4 and a /112 IPv6 subnet. I am trying to use AnyIP feature of Linux as described [Here](https://blog.widodh.nl/2016/04/anyip-bind-a-whole-subnet-to-your-linux-machine/) to make my vps respond to global pings to any IP from the IPv6 subnet without having to assign every individual IP from the subnet (over 65000 IPs) to my interface.

Consider two VPSs with fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 that I configure in the same way as bellow:

Firstly, I add the local route:

```
ip -6 route add local aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:11::/112 dev lo
```

On both VPS I can ping any IP from the subnet from inside the VPS itself, locally.
So far so good. Then I install ndppd as a neighbour discovery protocol tool on both servers :

```
apt-get install ndppd -y
```

I will then make the configuration file at `/etc/ndppd.conf` as:

```
proxy eth0 {
    router no
    rule aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:11::/112 {
        static
    }
}
```

And then restart ndppd daemon:

```
systemctl restart ndppd
```

After doing so, I can ping all subnet IPs of VPS1 from any global IPv6 capable server, but VPS2 which has had the same procedure is only pingle for the single IPv6 assigned directly to its interface.

Outputs of `ip -6 route show` and `sysctl -a | grep ipv6` are the same on both servers.

Could this be because of the router to which VPS2 is connected? Does this mean I should not be able to feature AnyIP on VPS2?

How can I dig further into this problem? Maybe Check on VPS2 that why ping packets are not arriving or are not responded?

The provider itself says you have to assign IPs to your interface for both VPS1 and VPS2. Aren't they aware of AnyIP feature of Linux?

**UPDATE:**
On VPS2 if add any candidate IP from the subnet to the interface and quickly remove it that single candidate becomes usable. Strange!

```
ip -6 addr add aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:22:1234 dev eth0
ip -6 addr del aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:22:1234 dev eth0
```

Then IP `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:22:1234` becomes usable and globaly pingable. I observe no change in the routes after doing this add/remove thing.

Comment: I'm unsure what exactly your question has to do with Ubuntu?  It sounds like you're asking a generic networking question, not an Ubuntu question.

Comment: Well I saw similar questions regarding AnyIP on this forum, so I thought it suits here.